# Socialite facebook driver get only first name

Tags: facebook, laravel, lumen, laravel-socialite

I know that this question is asked before but read before marking as dublicate.

So I am trying to get user's first name using Socialite 3.0, however I am not able to get it. I am getting the following error:

> Undefined index: first_name

I know it was possible before but not anymore. Is it impossible now? According to the Facebook's documentation, I should be able to get it.

I tried pretty much every possible answer I found by googling and from StackOverflow without success.

This is what I did:

```
$providerUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->userFromToken($request->fb_token);

$attributes = ['first_name' => $providerUser->user['first_name']];

return $attributes;
```

I also tried like this:

```
$driver = Socialite::driver('facebook')
        ->fields([
            'first_name'
        ]);

$user = $driver->userFromToken($request->fb_token);

return $user;
```

which gives me the following error:

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing
>   __toString(), "object" given.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did manage to get it working. So I had to do the following:

```
$providerUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')
        ->fields([
            'first_name'
        ])->stateless()->userFromToken($request->fb_token);

$first_name = $providerUser->user['first_name'];

return $first_name;
```